# I need a null values for repetative values

Tags: database

I have a question

```
state_id  state_name  city_id  city_name  
--------  ----------  -------  -----------
       1  Karnataka         1  Bangalore  
       1  Karnataka         2  Mysore     
       1  Karnataka         3  Hubli      
       2  Maharastra        1  abc        
       2  Maharastra        2  xyz
```

i should require output as below

```
state_id  state_name      city_id  city_name  
--------  ----------      -------  -----------
       1  Karnataka          1  Bangalore  
       1  null               2  Mysore     
       1  null               3  Hubli      
       2  Maharastra         1  abc        
       2  null               2  xyz
```

Kindly help me out of this

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried

Comment: Tag database(SQL Server/Oracle)

Comment: Use `lag(state_name) over (...)` and a `case` statement

Comment: You should really tag the database you are using, as the answer will be database dependent.

Answer (score 0):

As per above reference,

I have solved this,

Below is the script

SET @rn = 0;
SET @sid = 0;
SELECT state_id,city_id,city_name,@sid1:=@sid,@sid:=state_id,IF(IF(@sid1=@sid,@rn:=@rn+1,@rn:=1) = 1,state_name,NULL) AS state_name FROM t2;

state_id  city_id  city_name  @sid1:=@sid  @sid:=state_id  state_name

---

```
   1        1  Bangalore            0               1  Karnataka   
   1        2  Mysore               1               1  (NULL)      
   1        3  Hubli                1               1  (NULL)      
   2        1  abc                  1               2  Maharastra  
   2        2  xyz                  2               2  (NULL)
```

Thanks for the hint given